# Calculate the date of an American holiday given specific year in R

Tags: r, date

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the date of these American holidays:

1. Martin Luther King Jr. Day (every 3rd Monday of January)
2. Memorial Day (every last Monday of May)
3. Thanksgiving (every 4th Thursday of November)

Is it possible to come up with a function(s) to calculate the date with a given year and how?

Many thanks in advance.

*EDIT*
Rui Barradas answer works well, but I found another package called `dateTime`, it is even more simple and straightforward. I will include the function I came up with (please keep in mind that I am giving the function a sequence of years and end up with vectors of holidays).

```
years = seq(2020,2050)
library(timeDate)
MLKDays = vector()
memorialDays = vector()
thanksginingDays = vector()
nonFixedHolidays= function(y)
{
  for(yr in y)
  {
    MLKDays <<- c(MLKDays,toString(USMLKingsBirthday(yr)))
    memorialDays <<- c(memorialDays,toString(USMemorialDay(yr)))
    thanksginingDays <<- c(memorialDays,toString(USThanksgivingDay(yr)))
  }
}
nonFixedHolidays(years)
```

Comment: your question does not seem to be about programming, but more about atronomy/mathematics. Maybe you should consider asking to an other stack exchange ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `tis` includes functions on US federal holidays.
The output of function `holidays` are numbers representing `YYYYMMDD` and must be further processed.

```
hld <- tis::holidays(2020)
holid <- as.Date(as.character(hld), format = "%Y%m%d")
names(holid) <- names(hld)

holid
#    NewYears       MLKing   GWBirthday     Memorial        Labor 
#"2020-01-01" "2020-01-20" "2020-02-17" "2020-05-25" "2020-09-07" 
#    Columbus     Veterans Thanksgiving    Christmas 
#"2020-10-12" "2020-11-11" "2020-11-26" "2020-12-25"
```

And to keep only the ones in the question, use `grep`.

```
i <- grep("MLK|Memorial|Thanks", names(hld), ignore.case = TRUE)
holid[i]
#      MLKing     Memorial Thanksgiving 
#"2020-01-20" "2020-05-25" "2020-11-26"
```